# How to encode an ordered tree into bit sequence more efficiantly

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree

Suppose we want to save the shape of an ordered tree of n node, each node has maximal 2 children.
If it is a binary tree, we must use 2n bits. Since in our situation, we don't have left or right child, they are the same, so we must have some redundant sequences. 
So, can we encode it in a better way? It seems each node still have 3 cases, no child, one child, two children, but can we store it in less than 2 bits? Or in total have a better constant than 2?

Comment: It might be possible but I doubt it. You can reconstruct a tree with both pre-order + in-order traversal, but not with only one of them [nor with post-order traversal], so you are again "stuck" with the 2 constant with this approach.

Comment: p.s. It is 2n words and not bits, each pointer to a node contains more then a bit.

Comment: @amit He is just storing shape of the tree. So it is 2n bits.

Comment: @ElKamina: thanks for clarifying, I missed that.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to store the 2n bits as you mention and then to use [huffman coding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding) or other [lossless data compression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossless_data_compression) technique to compress this data.

I don't think you can achieve a better worst case bound, but on the average case - it should save you some space.

Comment: If we don't have the constraint that each node has at most 2 children, then it is proofed that the best we can do is using 2n plus something. But in this case I still think it might be done.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to approach it:

1. Encode multi-level sub-trees. Eg: at maximum level two you can have four shapes: (), (a), (a->b) and (a<-b->c). Now use 0,10,110,111 for each of these cases. For a simple 2 level complete tree coding is: 111 0 0. A 3 level complete tree is: 111,10,10. For 4 level complete tree this becomes: 111 111 111 0 0 0 0 . The assignments are arbitrary. You can use hoffman coding scheme (as amit mentioned) to find the optimal encoding. This encoding scheme is worse for chains. For a pure chain you need 3n-2 bits to store.
2. Do the 2n bit coding and then compress with any compression algorithms.

=== Another Approach ===

In the normal representation for every node you can have one of these three options: 00, 01, 11. Now, take three nodes at a time. You can have total 27 combinations. You can store each of those combinations in 5 bits. This way the average storage needed becomes 5/3 instead on 2 bits. Further, you can try to combine any number of nodes you like. See the following table for compression rates:

As you can see, if you combine 10 nodes together you reduce the storage space by a factor of 1.25 (i.e. space reduced by 20%)

```
naive_length compr_length compr_factor
2 2 1.0
4 4 1.0
6 5 1.2
8 7 1.14285714286
10 8 1.25
12 10 1.2
14 12 1.16666666667
16 13 1.23076923077
18 15 1.2
20 16 1.25
22 18 1.22222222222
24 20 1.2
26 21 1.2380952381
28 23 1.21739130435
30 24 1.25
32 26 1.23076923077
34 27 1.25925925926
```

Comment: Thanks, @ElKamina, but it performs worse when the tree is highly unbalanced. Is it possible to get a better structure without compress?

Comment: @user22997 Can you provide me the counts of each shape in your tree (i.e counts of (), (a), (a->b) and (a<-b->c) )?

Comment: @user22997 Don't worry about the counts. Use the new approach I describe in my solution.

Comment: Great approach, @ElKamina! But another question comes, that in this approach, how do we know the best numbers of the nodes combinations? Which I mean, a lower bound of this constant.

Comment: @user22997 The upper bound is log_3(4) = 1.2618595071429148 . See information entropy for more details.

Comment: ha, @ElKamina, I was guessing entropy might involved, that's really hard.

Comment: @user22997 You can compress 58 bits together for a compression rate of 1.26086956522. But you would need 32 petabytes to store the dictionary.

Comment: Yes, @ElKamina, when compress more bits, more problems show up, maybe 10 is good enough in practice.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, if a node has one child, it's not a left or right child, i.e. you don't distinguish left and right in case of one child. Then I think it can be done in (log 3) n where the log is base 2.

You describe the tree by a preorder traversal, for every node you write the number of children (0, 1 or 2). This creates a number of base 3 of length n (in fact length n - 1, the last node will always have zero children). There are exactly 3^(n - 1) such numbers, this can be encoded in binary in (log 3) (n - 1) ~= 1.59 (n - 1).

One can use O(log n) bits to write the number of bits in the beginning of the encoded bitstring.

**Update: here is an [implementation](https://gist.github.com/1778963).**

Comment: Thanks, @aelguindy, I think you showed the constant could be n*log3, but is there such an encoding method?

Comment: Of course there is, I modified the answer and added a Python implementation.